# CSS style links not working with my navigation links

Tags: html, css

Trying to change colors when hovering over navigation links, never had a problem before but it will not work.

I have my navigation in several div's, I tried to set my a link style to all divs, nothing changes at all. I originally made my code in a CSS class. Trying to make a responsive website at home, didn't have links in the navigation bar originally, just text.

```css
 a.navBar:link {color: white; text-decoration: none; }
    a.navBar:visited {color: white; text-decoration: none; }
    a.navBar:hover {color: #16262E; text-decoration: underline; }
    a.navBar:active {color: white; text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
 <div id="outerWrapper"> </div>
    <div id="navWrapper">
    <div id="navInnerWrapper">
  <div id="navBar">
        <ul>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I just want white text as navigation links that turn #16262E when the mouse is hovering over the link. Not receiving any errors, it just doesn't change from the default blue, underlined links.

Answer (score 1):

> **Step 1**

Remove `a` from starting of `a.navBar`.

> **Step 2**

Change `.navBar` to `#navBar` you are declaring **id attribute**  in element `<div id="navBar">`.

> **Step 3**

Add `space` and `a` between `#navbar` and `Pseudo-elements`.

Below code snippet have all above mentioned fixes. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
body {
   background-color:grey;
}
#navBar a:link {color: white; text-decoration: none; }
#navBar a:visited {color: white; text-decoration: none; }
#navBar a:hover {color: #16262E; text-decoration: underline; }
#navBar a:active {color: white; text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <div id="navWrapper">
    <div id="navInnerWrapper">
      <div id="navBar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

a.navBar means that you are selecting a link tag wich have class 'navBar'. This selector does not exist.
No link tag have a class navBar.
To solve this you can apply color changing when you hover the list tag.
Use this selector :

#navBar ul li:hover a {color : #000fff}

This means that when you hover li (which is located inside #navBar) change the link color

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <body>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="navBar" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBar" href="#">Our Work</a></li>
        <li><a class="navBar" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </body>
```

I have removed other div which are not nested properly.
Now put CSS inside "style" tag.
I will suggest to change either text-color or background-color, as text isn't visible on white background.